# How do I make a collison while someone is holding a button

Tags: lua, coronasdk, game-physics

So I have this cube which if the player clicks on a button moves. I also have this block which if the cube collides with, the cube will get sent back to a start position. I have tried my best but I can't seem to get both of them working correctly together. With my code, the cube get's glitchy and moves all over the screen between the block and start position. This is if the button is still pressed. If it is released at the same moment of collision it does work, but obviously the players won't be paying attention to that.

```
function touchHandler( event )
if event.phase == "began" then
    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( event.target )
    event.target.isFocus = true
    Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", enterFrameListener )
    holding = true
elseif event.target.isFocus then
    if event.phase == "moved" then
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        holding = false
        Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", enterFrameListener )
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
        event.target.isFocus = false
    end
end
return true
end
leftbutton:addEventListener( "touch", touchHandler )
```

This is the code for the collision:

```
 function onCollision( event )

if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
  transition.cancel( )
  transition.moveTo( cube, {time = 0, x = 35, y = 35} )

end
return true
end
redblock:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
```

Also: whenever the cube falls on an edge of the redblock and starts spinning and gets sent back to start. It keeps spinning and it starts moving on its own.

I hope someone can help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are still in the "moved" phase during the collision hence why the block tries to reset, but is then dragged around afterwards. Once you detect the collision, you need to remove the event handler from the "leftbutton" so that the touch event is no longer in progress.